# EAV attrubute load value from DB - low level code

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav

During some tasks, I was not aware of exactly how Magento loads values for attributes that are available. for example, if we have loaded Product Model and attributes in $product->getData(). Which classes and methods are responsible for loading text attribute values?

I'm searching how Magento loads attribute values for `\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product` but cant figure it out. I ran debug over and over again. but, it's a massive object-oriented relations code. Can anyone point to the place that is responsible for that? Xdebug points me to `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute` but the magic happens there and we have value :).

But, I want to know how it's working now?

PS. happy for me that it was not needed for the task, but now I need to figure out how it work for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load product in Magento with 2 ways, load single product and load collection. As I correct understand you are interest how Magento EAV works for single load. In this case:

The following methods are generally doing the same

- `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::get()`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getById()`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::load()`

**How it works**

1. Product Model pass load to it resource model `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product`.
2. Resource model load base entity row and call `loadAttributesForObject`method to determine which attribute should be loaded. By default uses `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeLoader::loadAllAttributes` logic.
3. Resource Model delegate load attributes to Entity Manager (`\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager::load`) and pass product model.
4. Entity Manager detect `read` (`\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read`) operation from `\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\OperationPool`
5. Based on entity metadata Read Operation calls read attributes (`\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadAttributes::execute`) and read extensions (`\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadExtensions::execute`) in `execute` method
6. Based on Attribute Pool (`\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\AttributePool`) the system collect `read` actions for entity (see `di.xml`)
7. The system runs `execute` for each actions and loads default attributes data in `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\ReadHandler::execute` and collect product data
8. Hydrator (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Hydrator`) sets collected data into product model

Comment: So when I load product by Product::load(), no attribute_model or attribute backend_model or attribute frontend_model is used to get attribute value? I'm searching for the point where during the load of product, attribute model is touched (or it's not). BTW, thank you for comprehensive answer.

Comment: If you are mean product attribute backend models - they are process already loaded data and calls on after load logic in `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity::_afterLoad`